# Create a dropdown with only two choices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an app that lets users create two types of charts: bar chart and line chart. So on the create and edit pages, I want to display a simple dropdown field with these options (as well as blank as the default value if it's the Create.cshtml).

I want to keep the business logic in my Charts model, so I did this:

```
public class Chart {
    public int ChartID { get; set; }
    public ChartType TypeOfChart { get; set; }

    public enum ChartType {
        Bar,
        Line
    }
}
```

My thought is that I'll just add to this enum property when I'm implementing new chart types in my app, and it will propagate from there to all the views.

Then in my Edit.cshtml, I did this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypeOfChart, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(ChartType))),  new { @class = "form-control" })
```

However, in the above line, it gives an error:

```
The type or namespace name 'ChartType' could not be found (are you missing a using or assembly reference?)
```

Is there an easier way to do this? I feel like this should be super easy to do, but I've been grappling with it for hours.

If I do this, it works:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypeOfChart, new SelectList(new string[] {"Bar", "Line"}),new { @class = "form-control" })
```

But when I click save, it doesn't update. (And I also think hardcoding the options into the view like that isn't good practice.)

Comment: Since you using mvc-5, why not use the `EnumDropDownListFor()` method? But it would need to be `typeof(Chart.ChartType)` - its a nested enum. Probably easier to move the `enum` definition outside of the class.

Comment: I get an error that says `'Chart' does not contain a definition for 'ChartType'`, which is strange because it clearly does.

Comment: And your second option (hardcoding the values) also works fine and is correctly bound when submitting the form)

Comment: IMHO, this would be better done as an array of strings.  Using enums in this manner always gives me a slight churning feeling in the pit of my stomache.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: if I do `SelectList(new string[] { "Bar", "Line"})` it doesn't put the value attributes inside the `<select>` tags, which is why the values don't get submitted. The generated HTML is just `<option>Bar</option>`.

Comment: It does not need to. If `<option>` elements do not have a `value` attribute, then the value posted back is the display text. Your code works fine. And its not `<select>Bar</select>` - you code outputs `<select name="TypeOfChart" id="TypeOfChart"><option>Bar</option><option>Line</option></select>`

Comment: OK, I think I figured it out. When I mouseovered the `Chart` object, it said it was `class System.Web.Helpers.Chart`, which is not my chart... I had to reference the full name, `MyProject.Models.Chart.ChartType` and it worked.

Comment: And regarding the type not saving, the HttpPost Edit method was bound to the wrong property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `ChartType` enum is nested in the `Chart` class, so you need to use `Chart.ChartType`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TypeOfChart, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Chart.ChartType))), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

From the comments, your also have another assembly named `Chart`, in which case you need the fully qualified name

```
MyProject.Models.Chart.ChartType
```